# How to Get all allow attributes of a product in magento2 and show allow attributes in single product page?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I want to get all allow attributes of a product in single page.

In magento 1.7 i was using below code :

```
<?php $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes()); ?>
```

But how can i achieve same thing in magento 2 ?

Also I have to display all these attributes in single product page. So how to render configurable.phtml file inside single product page file?

Comment: you mean all the allowed configurable attributes for a configurable product or all the attributes of a certain product (simple, configurable, virtual, ...) ?

Comment: Yes @Marius. all the allowed configurable attributes for a configurable product

Answer (score 1):

If you have a product object then you can it configurable product

> ```
>  public function __construct(     ...
>     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,     ....) {     ....
>     $this->arrayUtils = $arrayUtils;  .....
> }
>
> public function decorateArray($array, $prefix = 'decorated_', $forceSetAll = false)
> {
>     return $this->arrayUtils->decorateArray( $_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($_product), $prefix, $forceSetAll);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento-2 you can use like this.

```
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
```

Comment: I am using this. But its not working...:(

Comment: In Which file you are used ?

Comment: I am Using configurable.phtml file inside Magento_catalog/product/view/type/options/ also i tried to use view.phtml file inside MAgento_catalog/product/view.phtml file.

Comment: If i use this in configurable.phtml file, Then i have to call configurable.phtml file in view.phtml . and in magento 1.7, configurable.phtml file was calling from container1 or container2. And i am not getting this thing also. what is container1 and container2 which are using in catalog.xml file. They are calling in view.phtml file like this `<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true);  ?>`. Totally confused, what is happening in magento 1.7 and what to do to achieve this things in magento2. :(

Comment: There is a wrong file path.  You have to use this file in your theme vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Comment: Thanks. also can you please tell me how to call that configurable.phtml file inside Magento_catalog/product/view.phtml file?

Comment: There is no files view.phtml file in Magento_catalog/product/view.phtml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49216/discussion-between-yudi-and-s-h-patel).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
$this->_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($this->_product);
```

May be it will help you.